# Convert XSD to JSON

Tags: jackson

I have a requirement like I have an XSD or XML file and I generated POJO's from XSD or XML with XJC(Compiler). My XML file has a data like for example Person is the root element and he has list of addresses. So when I generate POJO's I can get list addresses from that POJO.

Now My requirement is I will generate POJO's, So when I call getAddresses() I want a JSON String instead of List of Strings. Is it possible ......??????

One of my friend said it is possible with Jackson annotations. But how can I start with that..?

If it possible Can anyone provide some sample code snippet or point me to in right direction.

Comment: Do you simply want to know how to generate a JSON string from a List of objects with Jackson? Or you are asking for the template code to generate a class with Jackson annotations on it?